# Appending a Boolean array

Tags: python, matplotlib, voxels

Ok, I'm new to programming and this might be something everybody knows...

I'm creating a game, and one of the features I'm intending to add is a 3D room map that I plan on generating with code. The problem I'm facing is that I need to append a Boolean array or whatever it's called without knowing how many elements it's going to contain.
Here is the test code and the problem highlighted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import random as rd

x,y,z = np.indices((8,8,8))

Lines = []

#Random straight lines
for i in range(4):
    rd.choice([
    Lines.append((x == rd.randint(0,8)) & (y == rd.randint(0,8))),
    Lines.append((y == rd.randint(0,8)) & (z == rd.randint(0,8))),
    Lines.append((x == rd.randint(0,8)) & (z == rd.randint(0,8))),
    ])
cols.append('r')

Voxels = Lines[0] | Lines[1] | Lines[2] | Lines[3] #I need to generate this 
#not Hard code it
colors = np.empty(Voxels.shape, dtype=object)
for i in range(len(Lines)):
    colors[Lines[i]]= 'r'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(Voxels, facecolors = colors, edgecolor='c')

plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do with your original line would be equal to :

```
Voxels = Lines[0] | Lines[1]
Voxels = Voxels | Lines[2]
Voxels = Voxels | Lines[3]
```

As the operations are done from left to right. Using parenthesis, it would look like :

```
Voxels = (((Lines[0] | Lines[1]) | Lines[2]) | Lines[3])
```

So, instead of doing...

```
Voxels = Lines[0] | Lines[1] | Lines[2] | Lines[3]
```

You should do...

```
Voxels = Lines[0]
for line in Lines[1:4]:
    Voxels = Voxels | line
```

And if you want to do more than the 4 first Lines, you could just do `for line in Lines[1:]`. I did this at the beginning, and it bugged me not to get the same result as you're original hardcoded example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, originally I circumvented the issue by drawing the lines individually in order of the list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import random as rd
W = 15
H = 15
D = 15
NoPlane = 5
NoLine = 10

Lines = []
Planes = []
Cubes = []
Spheres = []

x,y,z = np.indices((W,H,D))
#Random straight lines| Lines only run up and down
for i in range(NoLine):
    Lines.append(
        (x == rd.randint(0,W)) & (y == rd.randint(0,D)) & (z >= 
    rd.randint(0,int(H/2))) & (z <= rd.randint(int(H/2),D))
        )


#random Levels| Levels run horosontaly
for i in range(NoPlane):
    Planes.append((z == rd.randint(0,H)) & (x >= rd.randint(0,int(W/2))) & 
    (z <= rd.randint(int(W/2),W)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
#Draw each thing individualy instead of all at once
for i in range(len(Lines)):
    ax.voxels(Lines[i], facecolors = 'r', edgecolor='c')
for i in range(len(Planes)):
    ax.voxels(Planes[i], facecolors = 'b', edgecolor='r')

ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
plt.show()
```

But this method is too brute force.